# JavaFX Button which adds and removes Checkboxes

Tags: javafx

I was trying to create a button which deletes checked CheckBox but don't know how to make "cb" the same as in the Adding button.

```
package sample;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;




public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button add;
    @FXML
    private Button delete;
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;
    @FXML
    private TextField text;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cb;



    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void onAdd(ActionEvent e) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text.getText());
        vbox.getChildren().add(cb);
        if (text.getText().matches("")) {
            vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
        }

    }
    @FXML
    public void onDelete(ActionEvent e) {

        if(cb.isSelected()){
                vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
            }
        }

    }
```

The "cb" in onAdd event isn't the same as in onDelete event. How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it's possible to add multiple `CheckBox`es with the code you've posted. It's unclear which one should be removed. Of course you can access the children the way you access any other list elements. You deed to add a cast of course, since `children` is a `List<Node>`. If all children of `vbox` are `CheckBox`es, you could simply iterate through all the children and remove all those `CheckBox`es that are selected (assuming this is the functionality you're trying to achieve).

```
vbox.getChildren().removeIf(child -> ((CheckBox) child).isSelected());
```

If this is not the case, you could store the elements in a `List<CheckBox>` field:

```
private final List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

@FXML
public void onAdd(ActionEvent e) {
    if (text.getText().isEmpty()) { // alternative: text.getText().equals(""); matches is for regular expressions
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text.getText());
        vbox.getChildren().add(cb);
        checkBoxes.add(cb);
    }
}

@FXML
public void onDelete(ActionEvent e) {

    Iterator<CheckBox> iter = checkBoxes.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        CheckBox cb = iter.next();
        if (cb.isSelected()) {
            // remove from both vbox and checkBoxes
            vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```